# Cursor disappears when adding a space in the question title on Android

Tags: bug, questions, editor, android, mobile-chrome

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Type "In which order does Windows Explorer sort folders when sorting the results of the search by size" as the question title.
2. Place the cursor at the end of the question title.
3. Add a space
4. You'll see the cursor disappears and Chrome showing just the beginning of the question title:

[image]

That's annoying when writing the question title.

Comment: I've had this same issue when entering text in the description fields for post edits (on Chrome on Android) for a little while - but haven't made the time to isolate the exact conditions to reproduce.

Comment: This Bug Report: "[Cursor position jumps back on white spaces in Mobile Chrome on Android #30](https://github.com/signavio/react-mentions/issues/30#issue-87381477)" on GitHub gives the same STR, producing the same resulting misbehavior on the Chrome browser (not on FF). The referenced upstream [report on Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=503132) was closed due to abandonment, not fixed; though a workaround for the browser bug was offered in the GitHub report.

Comment: @Rob nice find, thanks!